# How to read in KML file properly in R, or separate out lumped variables into columns

Tags: r, kml, r-sf

I read in a KML file, using the following:

`clinics = st_read(dsn = "Data/clinics-kml.kml","CLINICS")`

However, all my variables (except for the coordinates) got lumped into 1 column under `Description` (see below link).

What's the best way to separate the variables out? Alternatively, is there a way to import KML files properly to avoid this issue? [You may view the screenshot of the problem here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hftop.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the data or sample of the data? I'm still interested in helping you resolve this without resorting to QGIS.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it from here, https://data.gov.sg/dataset/chas-clinics.

Comment: Please always add a full code including `library(tidyverse);
library(sf)` etc, hence the downvote. You can't do `st_read` without loading the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem (or maybe not) is that the *Description* column has an html table as a string for each observation. That is fine if you want to parse that html string and get a pretty table for example when creating an interactive web map. But it can be a headache if you just want the data inside.

So, it's possible to do all the process within R just following these steps:

1. Download the KML file from internet
2. Unzip the downloaded file
3. Read the KML file as a Spatial object
4. Get the attributes for each observation
5. Bind the attributes to each observation as new columns

All the code is commented, see below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

# 1) Download the kml file
moh_chas_clinics <- GET("https://data.gov.sg/dataset/31e92629-980d-4672-af33-cec147c18102/download",
                        write_disk(here::here("moh_chas_clinics.zip"), overwrite = TRUE))

# 2) Unzip the downloaded zip file 
unzip(here::here("moh_chas_clinics.zip"))

# 3) Read the KML file as a Spatial object
moh_chas_clinics <- read_sf(here::here("chas-clinics-kml.kml"))

# Watch data
moh_chas_clinics %>%
  glimpse()

# See map
mapview(moh_chas_clinics)

# 4) Get the attributes for each observation

# Option a) Using a simple lapply
attributes <- lapply(X = 1:nrow(moh_chas_clinics), 
                     FUN = function(x) {

                       moh_chas_clinics %>% 
                         slice(x) %>%
                         pull(Description) %>%
                         read_html() %>%
                         html_node("table") %>%
                         html_table(header = TRUE, trim = TRUE, dec = ".", fill = TRUE) %>%
                         as_tibble(.name_repair = ~ make.names(c("Attribute", "Value"))) %>% 
                         pivot_wider(names_from = Attribute, values_from = Value)

                     })

# Option b) Using a Parallel lapply (faster)
future::plan("multisession")

attributes <- future.apply::future_lapply(X = 1:nrow(moh_chas_clinics), 
                                          FUN = function(x) {

                                            moh_chas_clinics %>% 
                                              slice(x) %>%
                                              pull(Description) %>%
                                              read_html() %>%
                                              html_node("table") %>%
                                              html_table(header = TRUE, trim = TRUE, dec = ".", fill = TRUE) %>%
                                              as_tibble(.name_repair = ~ make.names(c("Attribute", "Value"))) %>% 
                                              pivot_wider(names_from = Attribute, values_from = Value)

                                          })

# 5) Bind the attributes to each observation as new columns
moh_chas_clinics_attr <- 
  moh_chas_clinics %>%
  bind_cols(bind_rows(attributes)) %>%
  select(-Description)

# Watch new data
moh_chas_clinics_attr %>%
  glimpse()

# New map
mapview(moh_chas_clinics_attr, 
        zcol = "CLINIC_PROGRAMME_CODE", 
        layer.name = "Clinic Programme Code")
```

A final map as an example showing all the attributes for a point and coloured by "Clinic Programme Code":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an alternative way by using QGIS to convert KML to SHP. Then read it as SHP into R.

Answer (score 0):

i got the following answer for option 1

Error in `repaired_names()`:
! Repaired names have length 2 instead of length 15.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

option 2
Error in vec_size() : `x` must be a vector, not a <sfc_POINT/sfc> object.